# Find the area of the region bounded by the given curves.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> $$y= \sin^2x, \text{ for } -\frac{\pi}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$$

I have no idea how to attempt this.

Please, any guide as to how to do this step by step would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Do you know integrals? $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sin^2xdx$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sin^2\,xdx &= \\
2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin^2x\,dx &= \\
 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}\,dx &= \\
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{1-\cos 2x}\,dx &= \\
x-\frac{\sin 2x}{2}\Bigg|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

Integration gives us are under the curve,
.

$$\int_{-π/4}^{π/4} \sin^2 x dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-π/4}^{π/4} 2\sin^2 x dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-π/4}^{π/4}  (1-\cos 2x) dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\int_{-π/4}^{π/4} 1 dx-\int_{-π/4}^{π/4}  (\cos 2x) dx)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{π}{2}-[\frac{\sin 2x}{2}]_{-π/4}^{π/4})$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{π}{2}-(\frac{1+1}{2}))$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{π}{2}-(1))$$
$$\frac{π-2}{4}$$
$$\approx 0.285398$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin^2xdx=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1-\cos2x)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}$$